# How to slide in a Hidden View from top

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

I would like to implement a `View` that slides from the top when a Button/Image/Label on the `ActionBar` is clicked. I would like it to work like the default `DrawerLayout`, except from sliding from the left/right sides, it slides from the top-down in this case.

How can I go about this? Does Android have a default class or action that handles this?

What I've managed to get mentioning this solution, [AndroidSwipeLayout](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout). It however, does not really do what I am looking for.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: did you try  `view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` `view.animate()
    .translationY(view.getHeight())` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a button then call the following function from the click on that button like this.

```
clickMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        yourLinerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setLayoutAnim_slideDown(view);
    }
});
```

And here's the `setLayoutAnim_slideDown` function which will slide down the layout that you want to slide from top to down.

```
public void setLayoutAnim_slideDown(ViewGroup panel) {

    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

    Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);

    // Set the duration here for animation in millis. 
    animation.setDuration(2000);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        }
    });
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(
            set, 0.25f);
    panel.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
}
```

For example, my layout is like this.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="masud is noob"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="click me" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The items inside the `LinearLayout` named `slider` will animate here.

Comment: Thank you for your response @reaz-murshed. I'm guessing `yourLinerLayout` in `clickMe.setOnClickListener` is `slider` in the layout XML. What is `view` that is being passed to `public void setLayoutAnim_slideDown(ViewGroup panel)` in `setLayoutAnim_slideDown(view);` in `clickMe.setOnClickListener`? Is it anywhere in the XML, or is it `@+id/slider` in the XML.

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev remember the items inside the `slider` will animate.